# Having trouble using jquery textfill

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I've tried these two https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/ https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/1/ (innerTag: bbb vs .bbb) but I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot.

```
<div id="ccc" style='width: 100px; height: 50px;'>
    <span class="bbb">Lipsum</span>
</div>
```

```js
$('#ccc').textfill({
    minFontPixels: 24,
    innerTag: .bbb
});
```

Comment: you should use double quotes!!!

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano oops! i just copied from the readme. still not working :( https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/2/

Comment: i tried https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/4/ and it function as expected, once you correct the double quote issue, and RTM, maximum font pixel default is 40!!!

Comment: It is working here as well, can you tell us what your expected result is?

Comment: @Jordumus @Crisim I got it to work with span but just realized my cms was making a div. https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/5/ The readme says "Put the text inside of a `<span/>` child by default (see _Options_ to change this)" and then options says "| `innerTag`        | The child element tag to resize. We select it by using `$(innerTag + ':visible:first', container)` | `span` |". I'm not sure how to switch it to div.

Comment: you can write any selector in the innerTag, so `'div'` is acceptable. it will get the first div inside the `'#ccc'` element

Answer (score 0):

Text in an array should always be in quotes:

```
$('#ccc').textfill({
    minFontPixels: 24,
    innerTag: ".bbb" //This line changed!
});
```

This will solve your problem, as Crisim Il Numenoreano pointed out in the comments as well: http://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/4

Comment: I got it to work with span but just realized my cms was making a div. https://jsfiddle.net/7j607u2o/5/ The readme says "Put the text inside of a `<span/>` child by default (see _Options_ to change this)" and then options says "| `innerTag`        | The child element tag to resize. We select it by using `$(innerTag + ':visible:first', container)` | `span` |". I'm not sure how to switch it to div.